# How to remotely debug an iot device using google cloud platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, iot

Imagine having an iot device in a building miles away from you. The device encountered a problem and I want to debug remotely. Is there an place in gcp where I can do that ? (With aws, I can use [secure tunneling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/secure-tunneling.html) to establish a secure tunnel and debug the device remotely)

Comment: It depends of your sensor feature. How can you log on your device? with SSH?

Comment: You need to be a little bit more specific - what is your device and what do you mean by "debugging" it.

Comment: Have you considered device [logging](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/device-logs#device_debug_logging) in purpose of debugging?

Comment: @Tarmo let's say it's a raspberry and by remotely debugging it I mean access to the rasp remotely (after reading the logs for example) and solve the problem. Basically I just want to know if there is an equivalent of aws iot secure tunneling in gcp